# How to create mega menu in Angular Material

Tags: angular-material, angular6, materialize, angular-material2, angular7

I am trying to build multi level mega menu with Angular Material - `mat-menu`. Now the problem here with me is I wanted to have mega menu like in bootstrap like [this](https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/rN17z) but I ended up building [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5mg8f?file=app%2Fnested-menu-example.html) in Angular material. I have changed CSS for changing the width like this:

```
.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-width: 1px; 
   min-height: 1px; 
 }
 .cdk-overlay-pane {
   position: absolute;
   pointer-events: auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1000;
   display: flex;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
 }
```

How can I design mega menu in Angular Material like the image given below?

[image]

I am using Angular 7.3.1 (latest version).

Comment: Please describe what you mean by 'mega menu' for users that can't access your link or don't want to sign-in/reveal their personal information. An image might work as well (but some users won't be able to use those either).

Comment: I have updated the question and added image for illustration. I want to design the menu like in the image in Angular Material

Comment: Material Design does not use this pattern. MatMenu is for Material Design menus which are overlay or 'popup' type. The mega menu is nothing more than a toolbar with a roll down panel. You should be able to implement that with standard components.

Comment: Cant this be solved using custom css for mat menu-item

Comment: Probably not. It would be like using a hammer to drive screws - the wrong tool for the job. MatMenu does not offer precise control of positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is true that Material Design does not use this pattern. MatMenu is for Material Design menus which are overlay or 'popup' type. The mega menu is nothing more than a toolbar with a roll down panel as suggested by  [G.Tranter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9226213/g-tranter). But the mega menu can be achieved by writing custom css. I dont know is this a correct way to do or not. I have `mat-menu` like this is .html file

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="my-full-width-menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 3</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 4</button>
</mat-menu>
```

And added the following css for full-width of submenu in style.css

```
.mat-menu-panel {
  min-width: 90vw !important;
  max-width: 95vw !important;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Now the concern is of responsive design. For that purpose I need to write `@media Query` in the component css file like this

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  button.mat-menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
 }
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  button.mat-menu-item {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
 }
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  button.mat-menu-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
 }
}
/* very large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  button.mat-menu-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
 }
}
/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1550px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 1550px) {
  button.mat-menu-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
 }
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpcjxk?file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html) is the StackBlitz demo of mega menu in mat-menu. This works for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Question and finally I had to handle it by my self and I dont know its the correct way or not ; but its worked

```
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileManagementMenu" class="option-button">
          {{'ProfileManagement'|translate}}
        </button>
        <mat-menu #profileManagementMenu="matMenu" class="mega-menu" xPosition="before">
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start" class="p-1">
            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" class="p-1 config">
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col11'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col12'|translate}}
              </button>
            </div>
            <span class="border" style="opacity: .3"></span>
            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" class="p-1 config">
              <h7 fxLayoutAlign="center">header2</h7>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col21'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col22'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col23'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col24'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col25'|translate}}
              </button>
              <button mat-menu-item>
                {{'Col26'|translate}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-menu>
```

and its the scss:

```
.mega-menu .mat-menu-content {
  min-width: 112px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  outline: 0;
  background: none;
  color: white !important;

  :hover {
    background: none;
    color: white;

  }
}

.mat-menu-item:hover {
  background: #338ACF !important;
  color: white;
}

.mat-menu-content {
  min-width: 112px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .95;
  background: #2688d6b8;
  color: white !important;

}
```